# Put directories into trash in red hat

Tags: linux, redhat

Guys I am new to Linux ... please I want a command to put directory I made to trash in red hat Linux  6 in GUI mode ...
Any help is appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could delete your directory with the `rm -rf testdir` command. This is irremediable and does not use the trash.

Answer (score 2):

the trash bin in linux is simply a hidden folder like .Trash, so you simply have to move your files/folders to the bin folder in the same root :

```
mv test .Trash
```

Comment: I want a command to do so neither drag drop nor buttons

Comment: `mv testdir ~/.Trash` is a shell command.